# Xcode8 Beta EXC_BAD_ACCESS Error appears when creates weak references

Tags: swift, exc-bad-access, weak-references, xcode8

The following code is copied from the [Weak References section of the Official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH20-ID48)

```
class Person {
    let name: String
    init(name: String) { self.name = name }
    var apartment: Apartment?
    deinit { print("\(name) is being deinitialized") }
}

class Apartment {
    let unit: String
    init(unit: String) { self.unit = unit }
    weak var tenant: Person?
    deinit { print("Apartment \(unit) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Person?
var unit4A: Apartment?

john = Person(name: "John Appleseed")
unit4A = Apartment(unit: "4A")

john!.apartment = unit4A
unit4A!.tenant = john //Error!
```

It basically described the strong and weak reference relationship between a `person` type instance and an `Apartment` type instance (Please see the figure bellow)

[image]

However, when I run the code, I got an error.

Question: How can I fix it?

[image]

In reply of Mr. Alessandro Orrù, (I copy and pasted it again and it still gives me error)

[image]

Comment: I copied and pasted the same code in a playground and it works as expected. Are you sure you didn't change anything?

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù I've copied and pasted it again, it gives the error. One option you could try is copy and paste my code here and see if there is any error appears.

Comment: weird, it works fine for me.. what version of Xcode are you using to run this?

Comment: I used the Xcod8 Beta. I've tried it on my old version It works. it is the problem of Xcod8 "(

Comment: yes, just tried it on Xcode 8 beta and crashes as well. You should report a bug to http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: @AlessandroOrrù, Sure, I'll do it, thanks for provide the URL

Comment: Issue is not reproducible with the master release of Xcode8 (GM Build: 8A218a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This now works correctly - the bug has been fixed in XCode 8 GM Seed.

**Original Answer:**

It's a bug in playgrounds in or XCode8 beta 3.  I copied your code, tried the Apple example, and tried reducing it to the minimum:

```
class A { var b:B? }

class B { weak var a:A? }

let b = B()
let a = A()

a.b=b
b.a=a
```

All work as expected with XCode 7.3.1 and Swift 2.2.  All fail with XCode 8 beta 3 and Swift 3.  The error is:

```
error: Playground execution aborted: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT).
```

It's in playgrounds only - it's fine in an app.  (I tried a Mac OS command line program)